# Does drafting a rider slow that rider down?

Tags: drafting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does drafting cause resistance to the lead rider?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/10069/does-drafting-cause-resistance-to-the-lead-rider)

Would the lead rider notice any difference if there was another rider drafting behind them?